# Tensorflow installation made execution of basic programs slow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am new to ML. Just installed tensorflow through anaconda and it seems to have tremendously slow speeds. Even for basic printing like the following , the execution time was around 5 seconds

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(1+3)
```

[image]

How to fix this ?

Comment: No fix, but something to understand. When you import tensorflow, there are lots of log message gets printed and others. To compute the operations, use time module before and after the operations.

Comment: Is there a chance that my IDE is the problem, I am using VSCode, should I switch to Jupyter notebook or pycharm

Answer (score 0):

As correctly mentioned by @Innat, here importing tensorflow is taking a little time at first, which can be due to tensorflow dependency libraries loading, the tensorflow graph computation workflow and the system configuration you are using.

```
import time
Start = time.time()

import time
Start = time.time()

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

End = time.time()
Elapsed = End - Start
print(Elapsed)
```

Output:

```
2.12.0
2.8322582244873047
```

After once tensorflow import is done , this will take less time comparatively.

```
import time
Start = time.time()

print(tf.__version__)

End = time.time()
Elapsed = End - Start
print(Elapsed)
```

Output:

```
2.12.0
0.00013017654418945312
```

For the basic computation printing which does not require tensorflow, will take lesser time.

```
import time
Start = time.time()

print(1+3)

End = time.time()
Elapsed = End - Start
print(Elapsed)
```

Output:

```
4
0.0007178783416748047
```